# Woocommerce: Set tax to different custom value for each product calculated by price, cost and tax rate

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to set a custom tax value for each product in Woocommerce which calculates as follows:

```
(price - cost) * (0,19/1,19)
```

Because Woocommerce doesn't offer a field for the cost of a product I installed the [Cost of Goods - Woocommerce](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-cost-of-goods/) extension which allows to add this information to each product.

Then I went ahead to look for the function that calculates the taxes `(calc_tax( $price, $rates, $price_includes_tax = false, $deprecated = false)` and found the hook **'woocommerce_calc_tax'** where I guess I have to hook into in order to change the calculated tax:

```
apply_filters( 
  'woocommerce_calc_tax',  
  $taxes,  
  $price,  
  $rates,  
  $price_includes_tax,  
  $suppress_rounding 
);
```

In the file `[includes/class-wc-tax.php][2]`.

But since the hook offers only five parameter - none of which represents costs of a product. I have no idea how to pass the cost of a product to a function that hooks into this hook.

So my question is, how to pass the cost of a product (from Cost of Goods plugin) to this hook to use in a custom calculation of tax as described above.

Or is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Sorry but I think that you will not be able to get the cost of good price inside any hook in the `WC_Tax` class as is not possible to get the post Id or the product Id in those hooks… Just for info you can get the cost of good for a product ID using `$cog = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_wc_cog_cost', true );` …

Comment: Thanks, although that doesn't sound good... by chance do you know if there is another way to implement the custom tax calculation? thanks again

Comment: This looks like very complicated even to me, so I don't have any brillant idea for the moment. Very sorry. May be you could contact Cost of Goods plugin support, but I am pretty sure that they will not really help, and they will tell you to contact an expert developer…

Comment: There's always a way. Not too familiar with wordpress tho. Interested about the problem

Comment: @user3647971 Yes there is alway a way, I agree, but it is a real complicated development, so for StackOverFlow something too broad and not free… If this question is interesting to you, you might upvote it.

Comment: Have you tried adding a custom field to the product (hopefully not displayed to the customer!) with the cost of the item, assuming the price is what's shown to the customer, and using a function that's triggered in the cart to do your re-calculation taxes?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Display product's custom tax with product in cart and checkout, not added in product's price
// Remove, if not show this to user
function display_custom_tax_with_product_on_cart_and_checkout( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    $item = $cart_item['data'];
    $product_id = $item->get_id();
    $product_price = $item->get_price();
    
    // Do some magic here to get the cost of the product (use $product_id).
    $cost_of_product = $Get_Cost_Of_Product;

    if ( is_numeric( $cost_of_product ) ) {
        $custom_tax = round( ( $product_price - $cost_of_product ) * ( 0.19 / 1.19 ), 2 );
        $item_data[] = array(
            'name'  => __( 'Custom Tax on this is', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => $custom_tax,
        );
    }
    return $item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_tax_with_product_on_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2 );

// Get all product's total custom Tax and add that at total calculation
// this create field name "Total Custom Tax:" at cart and checkout
function add_custom_tax() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $custom_tax = 0;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $values ) {
        $item = $values['data'];
        if ( empty( $item ) ) {
            break;
        }

        $product_id = $item->get_id();
        $product_price = $item->get_price();

        // Do some magic here to get the cost of the product (use $product_id).
        $cost_of_product = $Get_Cost_Of_Product;

        if ( is_numeric( $cost_of_product ) ) {
            $custom_tax += round( ( $product_price - $cost_of_product ) * ( 0.19 / 1.19 ), 2 );
        }
    }

    if ( $custom_tax > 0 ) {
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Total Custom Tax:', $custom_tax, false );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_custom_tax' );
```

Bellow I added a image of cart page better understanding of my answer

[image: This is cart page after these custom tax code]

---

if this is not suitable for anyone, then [ntk4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5425664/ntk4)'s comment is also suggest a better way !

Comment: You need to explain your answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad, thank you for your suggestion, I already comment what functions does but from now on i'll give more explanation/clarification about my answer

Comment: I'm aware of that, yet, your answer is likely to be valued more by its readers if you add textual explanation.